# Issue in GDataXMLDocument when try [dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `GDataXMLDocument`. I need to parse very simple XML string. When I try to init XML with string I receive error:

```
-[myObj dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7afb5690
```

My string is:

```
<rootNode>
    <detail1>value</detail1>
    <detail2>value</detail2>
    <detail3>value</detail3>
    <detail4>value</detail4>
</rootNode>
```

The line of the error is:

```
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

where I need to encode my string no NSData, so I can init my parser with it.

I suppose the problem is in `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, but I can not understand why!

I am using ARC with NON ARC for `GDataXML` set in compilation options.

How to solve this?

P.S. I have a remark which might be important. I receive an array from SOAP service. I used [sudzc.com](http://sudzc.com) tool to create my classes. The SOAP service send to me array of structures. When I receive data using `po` command see what is inside and I decided that it consists of NSArray with XML sting inside. In general I extract each element of an array and try to parse it as XML to extract data I need.

May be I am wrong and that is the reason for that error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but I fix it casting once again to `NSString` with format using:

```
NSString *properStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];
```

I am not sure why I need this, but it is wotking now.